# How to insert null value to money datatype when there is a blank value in .csv file by using derived column in SSIS?

Tags: c#, sql, ssis

I am reading CSV file which contains column having money value and I need to import into SQL table having column (money datatype), if it contains null value then I need insert null value. How to do by using derived column in SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

```
select decode(trim(''),null,'null') from dual;
```

If you consider `trim('')` is `.CSV` file and which consider a blank value then the above decode statement help you to convert to null

EX:
suppose `.CSV` filled is TAB_VAL and value is blank (''):

```
declare
v_variable varchar2(10);
begin
  v_variable := decode(trim(TAB_VAL),null,'null');
end;
```